# Flutter downloading file to Both IOS and Android directory

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Hope everyone is enjoying their day,

I'm trying to create a download button where it get the file from a URL and saves it.

The two problems that I'm facing are, first on Android the file is not being stored in the download directory and second, on ios, the download button doesn't do anything.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        _isDownloading = !_isDownloading;
                      });
                      var dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

                      Dio dio = Dio();
                      dio.download(
                          'https://****/uploads/lesson_files/$attachment_url',
                          '${dir.path}/${widget.ctitle} | ${widget.day} | $video_title.$attachment_type',
                          onReceiveProgress: (actualbytes, totalbytes) {
                        var percentage = actualbytes / totalbytes * 100;
                        if (percentage < 100) {
                          _percentage = percentage / 100;
                          setState(() {
                            downloadMessage =
                                'Downloading... ${percentage.floor()}%';
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            downloadMessage = 'Successfully Downloaded';
                          });
                        }
                      });
                      dir.list(recursive: false).forEach((f) {
                        print(f);
                      });
                    },
                    label: Text('Donwload'),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
```

Comment: `on Android the file is not being stored in the download directory ` Then please tell where it is saved instead.

Comment: @blackapps My bad, so usually it saves it to InternalStorage/Android/data/com.domain.appname/

Comment: ???? That does not match getExternalStorageDirectory(); at all. Hard to believe. And why usually?

Comment: `InternalStorage/Android/data/com.domain.appname/` That is no valid full path. You as a programmer, do you mean full path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.domain.appname/` ? Also tell full path of `getExternalStorageDirectory()` .

Comment: @blackapps Why usually? because I can't find it anymore. And of course its /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.domain.appname/ but I thought you wanted to know the directory of where I found the file and not the "CODE of the directory" just wanted to simplify it.